# How to modify an Eigen::Matrix row passed to a ceres cost function?

Tags: eigen, ceres-solver

I have a matrix defined as follows:

`Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor > newEigenMat;`

I am passing it row by row to a Ceres cost function. The value I pass is:

`newEigenMat.row(i).data()`

I would like to modify this row from within the Ceres cost function.

If I try to access it as a normal Eigen vector like so:
`inputRow(i) = val;`

Ceres gives me the error: **inputRow cannot be used as a function**.

How can I do it correctly please?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the help section on how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). A vague description of your interface and use does not provide enough information to help you